# Is there any way to get back to same page while canceling an asyncdata api call via browsers's back button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have been using Nuxtjs and axios for API calls. In a page called post listing, once I select a post which suppose to navigate me to details page, while loading towards the page, once I click on browse's back button and try to get back to same listing page again without visiting the details page. It gives 404 and post not found error.

Is there any good way to prevent that?

Here is the code details page

```js
async asyncData({ $api, route, $auth, error }) {
    try {
      // console.log(route.params)
      const { feed } = await $api.Feed.feedDetails(
        route.params.id,
        $auth.loggedIn
      )
      if (route.query.origin === 'channel') {
        const { channel } = await $api.Channels.channelDetails(
          route.query.cId,
          $auth.loggedIn
        )
        return { feed, channel_details: channel }
      } else {
        return { feed }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Feed not found' })
    }
  },
```

I have this middleware in the page details page

```js
export default async function (context) {
  if (context.$auth.$state.loggedIn) {
    const params = {
      page: 1,
    }
    const { threads } = await context.$api.Messages.MessageThreadList(params)
    const { notifications } = await context.$api.Users.getNotifications({
      last_id: 0,
    })

    context.store.commit('addThreadList', threads)
    context.store.commit('addNotification', notifications)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your main issue is not canceling an axios call but rather understand why you do have such error. Could you please share the relevant parts of the 2 concerned files?

Comment: I have updated the code part @kissu

Comment: Could you please share the relevant parts of the **2** concerned files?

Comment: I have updated the code @kissu